# add nested json data to firestore document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to add nested json data to an existing document in firestore. I have tried one of the codes found online using nodeJs, but it replaced the document I had before. Can any one suggest a code snippet either in python or nodeJs or html? My document looks like this-

[image: Users db]

[image: with nested new collection]

[image: inside new collection]

Have tried the below code in nodejs

```
data && Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    const nestedContent = data[key];
    if (typeof nestedContent === "object") {
        Object.keys(nestedContent).forEach(docTitle => {
            admin.firestore()
                .collection(key)
                .doc(docTitle)
                .set(nestedContent[docTitle])
                .then((res) => {
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
            })
                .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: wat did u try...

Comment: Please edit the question with the code that you tried that didn't work the way you expect.  We need to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Without watching your code it's hard to say but something like this should work

```
firebase.firestore().collection("parentCollection").doc("idOfTheItemToMutate").collection("nestedCollection").add({
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2
})
```